# Failing test with bookshelf.js and bookshelf-validate

Tags: promise, mocha.js, bookshelf.js

I am new to node and I am just attempting at writing a simple backend blog API.  I am using bookshelf.js as the ORM and I am attempting to use bookshelf-validate in order to enforce requirements on an Article model that I made.  The validations I have included with the Article model are merely the isRequired validations on all fields (fields being title, author, and body).  One of my tests creates a new article with all the fields defined and the test is failing.  Here is my code,

```
//here is the bookshelf model 
const Bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf.config');

const Article = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'articles',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  validations: {
    title: {
      isRequired: true
    },
    author: {
      isRequired: true
    },
    body: {
      isRequired: true
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Article', Article);





//test file below

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const { expect, assert } = require('chai').use(chaiAsPromised);
const knex = require('knex')(require('../knexfile')[process.env.NODE_ENV]);

const Article = require('../models/article');

describe('Articles', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    return knex.migrate.rollback()
      .then(function () {
        return knex.migrate.latest();
      });
  });

  after(function () {
    return knex.migrate.rollback();
  });

  describe('test db', function () {
    it('should not have any models at start of test suite', function () {
      Article.forge().fetch().then(function (results) {
        expect(results).to.equal(null);
      });
    });
    it('should save a model to the db', function () {
      const article = new Article({
        title: 'first blog',
        author: 'john doe',
        body: 'blah blah'
      }).save();
      return expect(article).to.be.fulfilled;
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the gist as well https://gist.github.com/Euklidian-Space/bf10fd1a72bec9190867854d1ea309d9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `should save a model to the db` test is not taking asynchronicity into account. It may save the entry but the `expect()` call may come too early to get the fulfilled promise.

So replace

```
it('should save a model to the db', function () {
  const article = new Article({
    title: 'first blog',
    author: 'john doe',
    body: 'blah blah'
  }).save();
  return expect(article).to.be.fulfilled;
});
```

by something like

```
it('should save a model to the db', function (done) {
  const article = new Article({
    title: 'first blog',
    author: 'john doe',
    body: 'blah blah'
  })
  .save()
  .then(function () { done() })
  .catch(function (err) { done(err) });
});
```